# How to pass parameters from spring boot application to keycloak?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, url-parameters

I need to pass two params from spring boot application to keycloak and I have to evaluate the policy using that parameters.How do I do that? Should I pass claims? If yes,How should I do? How will i get those parameters in policy?